# Javascript performance - how to improve performance of little script

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, parallax

I recently made a website that uses window.scroll to add a class of 'active' to elements to trigger css3 animations. These animations though sometimes didnt fire and all in all the performance of the script was very slow. Today I was looking at [firefox parallax site](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/)
and noticed theirs never missed a 'trigger' and the performance was good but I cant find how they achieved this - anyone have any experience with sites like these?

my code looks like this at the moment...

```
$(window).scroll(function(){    
    if ( $('.trigger:in-viewport:first.trigger5').length )
    {
        $('[rel=counter]').addClass('active');
        $('[rel=discover]').removeClass('active');
        $('[rel=follow]').removeClass('active');
        $('[rel=sync]').removeClass('active');
    }
```

I have a feeling that its the use of jQuery and the viewport plugin..

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Performing DOM queries inside rapid-fire events like scroll and mousemove. Classic mistake.

Comment: Try caching your `$()` queries in variables outside of the `.scroll()` callback function. As it is now, every time a scroll event fires and your callback function is executed, the DOM is queried *five* times.

Comment: You may find this method useful http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Comment: Why every time, good advice in the comment and absolutely same answer written by different person?

Comment: @vp_arth Many times I have just enough time to write a quick comment, but not enough time to invest in writing good code to put into a well thought-out answer. I imagine many others are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and obvious thing:

```
var $window = $( window );
var DOM = {
    counter: $( '[rel=counter]' ),
    discover: $( '[rel=discover]' ),
    follow: $( '[rel=follow]' ),
    sync: $( '[rel=sync] ')
};

function doThingsOnScroll() {    
    if ( $( '.trigger:in-viewport:first.trigger5' ).length ) {
        DOM.counter.addClass('active');
        DOM.discover.removeClass('active');
        DOM.follow.removeClass('active');
        DOM.sync.removeClass('active');
    }
}

$window.scroll( doThingsOnScroll );
```

Like in comments: you must cache queries. Operations on DOM are realy heavy. Take elements once and use them.

Another thing which can help is underscore function throttle.
http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

```
var throttled = _.throttle( doThingsOnScroll, 100 );
$window.scroll( throttled );
```

Some time ago Paul Lewis wrote article about scrolling on html5rocks. I recommend to read it before fixing: [Scrolling Performance](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/)

EDIT: fixed `:in-viewport`. Thanks Bergi.

Comment: I don't know what plugin enables that `:in-viewport` selector, but it seems that is the only dynamic one that would be worth querying from a scroll event. If all jQuery selections are static, there's no need to `doThingsOnScroll`.

Comment: about throttle. It caches function call for 100ms, right?

Comment: @Bergi, How `[rel=xxx]` can be dynamic without additional js? agree with `:in-viewport`

Comment: @vp_arth: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The time is being spent in your jQuery selectors. Simply execute and store the selectors in variables first. Then use those variables in the future. Example:

```
var $firstTrigger = $('.trigger:in-viewport:first.trigger5');
var $counter = $('[rel=counter]');
var $discover = $('[rel=discover]');
var $follow = $('[rel=follow]');
var $sync = $('[rel=sync]');

$(window).scroll(function(){    
    if ( $firstTrigger.length )
    {
        $counter.addClass('active');
        $discover.removeClass('active');
        $follow.removeClass('active');
        $sync.removeClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: `$firstTrigger` has a very different selector.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how that got messed up.

Answer (score 0):

ignoring dom-heavy calls for now, your overall pattern is very CPU heavy thanks to the rapid-fire aspect of scroll().

we can call it only often instead of always for a big reduction in cpu, esspecially on mobile or other weak devices:

```
function doScroll(){    
    if ( $('.trigger:in-viewport:first.trigger5').length )
    {
        $('[rel=counter]').addClass('active');
        $('[rel=discover]').removeClass('active');
        $('[rel=follow]').removeClass('active');
        $('[rel=sync]').removeClass('active');
    }
}

$(window).scroll(function dome(){
  clearTimeout(dome.timer);
  dome.timer=setTimeout(doScroll, 100);
})
```

this goes for a frame-rate of 10FPS, feel free to adjust by altering the setTimeout duration.

caching the jQuery selectors might help some as well, but if you're over-firing scroll(), saving 25% in each execution will probably not be enough, but eliminating work will execute the code faster regardless of further optimization to be made.